# Format lsblk output to specific format

Tags: awk, formatting

I am looking for a way to show the lsblk output in a specific format.
I tried to use this:

```
lsblk -n -l -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT
```

and I need to convert this format below:

```
sda                 931.5G disk
sda1         ext4   923.8G part /
sda2                    1K part 
sda5         swap     7.8G part [SWAP]
```

To that format below and please note that it is necessary to ignore the empty columns when there is no file system or mount point.

```
device:sda
size:931.5G
type:disk
device:sda1
filesystem:ext4
size:923.8G
type:part
mountpoint:/
device:sda2
size:1K
type:part
device:sda5
filesystem:swap
size:7.8G
type:part
mountpoint:[SWAP]
```

I tried this command below so far:

```
lsblk -n -l -o NAME,TYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,FSTYPE | awk '{print $1":"$2":"$3":"$4":"$5}'
```

Comment: Try this for starters: `lsblk -n -l -o NAME,TYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,FSTYPE | awk '{print $1"\n"$2"\n"$3"\n"$4"\n"$5"\n---"}'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU awk for [FIELDWIDTHS](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Constant-Size):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split("device filesystem size type mountpoint",tags)
    FIELDWIDTHS = "12 7 7 5 *"
    OFS = ":"
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"",$i)
        if ( $i != "" ) {
            print tags[i], $i
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
device:sda
size:931.5G
type:disk
device:sda1
filesystem:ext4
size:923.8G
type:part
mountpoint:/
device:sda2
size:1K
type:part
device:sda5
filesystem:swap
size:7.8G
type:part
mountpoint:[SWAP]
```

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for the assistance. The code snippet worked 100% here.